# basic question about weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I study functional analysis and convex analysis by myself in order to understand convex optimization.Someone may think this question is easy, but it is difficult for me to understand proof in text book.So I post this question to understand proof in text book. Please tell me.

Text book says that

> In Hilbert space $H$, $x_n\rightarrow x_0, y_n \rightharpoonup y_0\implies \langle x_n,y_n\rangle\rightarrow\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$
>
> [Proof]
>
> $\{y_n\}$ is bounded. and $\|y_n\|\leq M(\forall n)$.
>
> |$\langle x_n,y_n\rangle-\langle x_0,y_0\rangle|\leq\|x_n-x_0\|M+\|x_0\|\|y_0-y_n\|\rightarrow0$

I have question about below relationship. How can we prove ?

$y_n\rightharpoonup y_0 \implies \|y_0 - y_n\|\rightarrow0$.

Reference

- Introduction to Nonlinear and Convex Analysis, Takahashi Wataru

Comment: No. $e_n \rightharpoonup 0$ for an ONB $(e_n)$

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Thanks comment. I edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Is the proof in the text wrong ?

below is my proof.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
|\langle x_n,y_n\rangle - \langle x_0,y_0\rangle | 
&=& |\langle x_n-x_0,y_n\rangle - \langle x_0,y_0-y_n\rangle |\\
&\leq& \|x_n-x_0\|\|y_n\|+|\langle x_0,y_0\rangle - \langle x_0,y_n\rangle|\\
&\leq& \|x_n-x_0\|M+|\langle x_0,y_0\rangle - \langle x_0,y_n\rangle|\\
&\rightarrow& 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This property only holds in a weaker form: If $y_n \rightharpoonup y_0$ and $\|y_n\| \to \|y_0\|$ then $y_n\to y_0$. This is because
$$ \|y_n - y_0\|^2 = \langle y_n - y_0, y_n - y_0\rangle = \|y_n\|^2 + \|y_0\|^2 - 2\langle y_0, y_n\rangle \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \|y_0\|^2 + \|y_0\|^2 - 2\|y_0\|^2 = 0$$

Comment: From this result, the proof of text book is wrong. Is it OK?

Comment: @user18000142 No, it is not. But note that $$ |\langle x_n,y_n\rangle - \langle x_0, y_n\rangle\| \leq \|x_n-x_0\|\|y_n\| \leq M\|x_n-x_0\|$$ which suffices to prove the result.

Comment: But text book doesn't assume that $\|y_n\| \rightarrow \|y_0\|$.

Comment: If text book assumes that $\|y_n\|\rightarrow\|y_0\|$, I can understand your comment.

Comment: @user18000142 As I said, the way the textbook does it is not correct, but you can still easily prove the result.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good at english. I misunderstand what you say... Thank you for comment !